# Deserializing Protobuf-Net objects using a filter

Tags: protobuf-net

I am using protobuf-net in one of our projects to serialize/deserialize a large set of homogeneous objects. It is working quite well and the speed is fantastic. Just have one question though. While deserializing is it possible to use linq (or any other mechanism) to specify a filter criteria, so that objects which only meet that criteria are loaded? It is fairly trivial to deserialize ALL the objects and then apply a linq filter but I want to reduce the number of objects loaded into memory. The filter criteria can be fairly dynamic, so a string kind of mechanism would be fantastic (something like dlinq?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is nothing built in, but if you have a clearly defined use-case it is something I could of course look at (I'm the author).

For now, I would suggest using some variant of:

```
var found = Serializer.DeserializeItems<A>(source, PrefixStyle.Base128,
         Serializer.ListItemTag).FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.Foo = "bar");

if(found != null) {...}
```

which will short-circuit when a match is found, and will release the objects for collection promptly (hopefully in gen-0). Or for multiple items, perhaps:

```
var list = Serializer.DeserializeItems<A>(source, PrefixStyle.Base128,
         Serializer.ListItemTag).Where(obj => obj.Foo = "bar").ToList();
```

(which again releases the non-matching items promptly)

To do this in the *general* case (especially for more complex queries) I can't think of a sane way to do it without materializing the object, so this is *probably* as close as you can get unless there is a very specific (and simple) scenario that *happens* to align nicely with the underlying data storage (for example, the filter is always on "tag 1").

Comment: Your second example (for multiple items) will do nicely for me. What will be the constraints on Foo (of obj.Foo)? I assume it can only be value type properties on obj itself? I understand and agree with what Iain is saying, but if non-matching items are promptly released (as you mention), then it would make my streaming code consume less memory and probably faster(?)... On a separate note, is it possible to have an API where you do the filtering AFTER materializing the object (I pass the lambda) -- again it will lead to you releasing the non-required objects faster?

Comment: @Sam at that point the object is fully materialized and you are just running a predicate past it, so you can do anything you like; that is just regular LINQ-to-Objects.

Comment: @Sam - just to make it explicit, that is all possible now via the existing API plus LINQ; no change is needed there.

Comment: Yes, I got that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you won't be able to treat your serialised data as anything but raw data until you've finished deserialising.
You may get some memory benefits from filtering as you go, but unless this is a problem it wouldn't be worth bothering.

You may be able to filter the incoming serialised representation, but weigh the amount of time and effort to do this against what you will save.

Most of the time (in a desktop or server environment) it's best to go the simple option that works, then go to something more complex if you *need* it later.

Comment: (strictly speaking not "text" in this case, but I agree with your overall points)